# Is it possible to overwrite Hadoop Configurations in SPARK?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Is it possible to overwrite Hadoop Configurations in SPARK so that NameNode IPs got automatically resolved? At present, I'm getting UnknownHostException because of existing Hadoop Configurations(which i can't modify as it might affect my regular HDFS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that is passed in with the prefix `spark.hadoop.` will be treated as a Hadoop configuration override.

```
val conf = new SparkConf
conf.set("spark.hadoop.HADOOPCONFKEY", "VALUE")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Or anything you pass into the `hadoopRDD` conf acts as the hadoop configuration values.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What keys should i set in HADOOPCONFKEY for automatically resolving Namenode IPs. I tried giving "spark.hadoop.dfs.ha.namenodes.nn", "spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.rpc-address.nn", "spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.http-address.nn" and other core-site & hdfs-site conf properties. But still i get UnknownHostException.

Comment: I'm not sure. That sounds to be more of a hadoop specific question.